# store image path in file or in database

Tags: database, image, storage, theory

As this post [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) indicates storing image path in database is at its best practice, then when and why do we have the need for storing or using file system in terms of xml or csv or etc?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? When do we need to store XML/CSV? When the business requirements indicate you do! Is this for a particular database type? if so, tag it.

Comment: its not for a particular database type, its more of a conceptual theory.

Comment: The database type implies the best practice. I understand that databases like HADOOP are good at storing documents, whereas relational databases aren't. Regardless your question is not very clear... we need to store XML and CSV and etc. when the business reuqirement and the technology dictates that we do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used Database to store the file path as it would minimize the data traffic size and reduce storage size since with images it is very easily to tend the database run out of juice in no time. Another advantage is that image should be served faster since it is simply reading from the file and do not need to go through database, it is one less layer to deal with.